# cropper js resize and crop with image magic

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemagick, cropper, cropperjs

How to perform resize and crop with ImageMagick using the data from [cropperjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)?

The user can upload a large image and zoom/pan to crop. Tried using blob but it looses too much quality and times out too often.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRVLp.jpg) from fiddle with the following data:

```
Original Width: 1280
Original Height: 720
Width: 424.8717011756327
Height: 238.9903319112934
X: -155.17118867901692
Y: -1.4989251522088705
Scale: 23.82
```

Tried with this but it crops the wrong area. Also tried scaling the original image but that's too big for the server to handle.

```
convert orignial.jpg -resize "1280x720^" -gravity center -crop 424x238+-155+-1 +repage result.jpg
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/1knw3a5e/

JS code:

```
$(function() {
    var image = $('#crop-image');
    var zoomSlider = document.getElementById('zoom-slider');
    var canvasSize = null;
    var pictureContainer = $('.picture-frame');
    var maxPictureContainerWidth = parseFloat(pictureContainer.css('max-width')) || 450;
    var maxPictureContainerHeight = parseFloat(pictureContainer.css('max-height')) || 350;
    var isSliderInUse = false;

    // Wall is in Cm, convert to Inches to work out pixel sizes at 300dpi
    var wallWpx = (0.393700787 * pictureContainer.attr('data-width')) * 300; // data-width is the wall width in pixels
    var wallHpx = (0.393700787 * pictureContainer.attr('data-height')) * 300; // data-height is the wall height in pixels

    var sampleImageScaleFactor = (image.attr('width') / image.attr('original-width'));

    var wallSize = {
        width: wallWpx * sampleImageScaleFactor, // scaling the wall size corresponding the sample size
        height: wallHpx * sampleImageScaleFactor,
        originalWidth: pictureContainer.attr('data-width'),
        originalHeight: pictureContainer.attr('data-height')
    };
    var wallAspectRatio = wallSize.originalWidth/wallSize.originalHeight;
    var pictureContainerSizes = {
        'width': maxPictureContainerWidth * (wallAspectRatio > 1 ? 1 : wallAspectRatio) ,
        'height': maxPictureContainerHeight / (wallAspectRatio > 1 ? wallAspectRatio : 1)
    };
    pictureContainer.css(pictureContainerSizes).removeClass('hidden');
    var zoomStep = 0.2;
    var biggerSide = null;

    var zoomModal = $('#modal-warning');
    var handleZoomHold, handleZoomFired;

    image.cropper({
        zoom: 0.2,
        guides: false,
        cropBoxResizable: false,
        cropBoxMovable: false,
        //viewMode: 3,
        dragMode: 'move',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        //width: canvasSize.width,
        //height: canvasSize.height,
        //aspectRatio: 1,
        toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false,
        zoomOnTouch: true,
        zoomOnWheel: true
    });  

    // Event
    image.on('built.cropper', function() {
        image.cropper('setCropBoxData', {
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            width: pictureContainerSizes.width,
            height: pictureContainerSizes.height
        });
        canvasSize = {
            width: image.cropper('getCropBoxData').width,
            height: image.cropper('getCropBoxData').height
        };
        biggerSide = canvasSize.width === image.cropper('getImageData').width ? 'width' : 'height';

        var savedCropperSettings = {
            sliceW: parseFloat($('input[name=sliceW]').val()),
            sliceH: parseFloat($('input[name=sliceH]').val()),
            sliceX: parseFloat($('input[name=sliceX]').val()),
            sliceY: parseFloat($('input[name=sliceY]').val()),
            scale: parseFloat($('input[name=scale]').val()) // saved adoptedZoomFactor
        };

        if (!savedCropperSettings.scale) {
            return;
        }

        /* restoring saved settings */
        image.cropper('zoomTo', canvasSize[biggerSide]/(wallSize[biggerSide]/savedCropperSettings.scale.toFixed(1)));

        var cropboxData = image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
        var scaleFactor = wallSize.originalHeight / cropboxData.height;
        image.cropper('setCanvasData', {
            left: savedCropperSettings.sliceX / scaleFactor + cropboxData.left,
            top: savedCropperSettings.sliceY / scaleFactor + cropboxData.top
        });
    });

    var adoptedZoomFactor = NaN;
    var adoptedZoomElement = $('#adoptedZoom');
    image.on('crop.cropper', function() {
        var data = image.cropper('getData');
        var canvasData = image.cropper('getCanvasData');
        var cropboxData = image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
        var scaleFactor = wallSize.originalHeight / cropboxData.height;
        adoptedZoomFactor = parseFloat((wallSize[biggerSide] / data[biggerSide]).toFixed(2));
        adoptedZoomElement.text(adoptedZoomFactor);

        $('input[name=sliceW]').val(canvasData.width * scaleFactor);
        $('input[name=sliceH]').val(canvasData.height * scaleFactor);
        $('input[name=sliceX]').val((canvasData.left - cropboxData.left) * scaleFactor);
        $('input[name=sliceY]').val(canvasData.top * scaleFactor);
        $('input[name=scale]').val(adoptedZoomFactor);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

That cropper tool does not work correctly on my Mac in Safari or Firefox or Chrome. It does not respect the scale values that are entered. It always comes out with results of scale=1. Perhaps I am doing it wrong.

But if you want to do it in ImageMagick, the correct way would be:

Original:

[image]

Cropper Screen Snap:

[image]

Cropper Result (dimensions 320x180; still scale=1):

[image]

Using ImageMagick (dimensions 640x360):

```
ww=320
hh=180
xx=40
yy=60
rotate=0
scale=2
scale=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$scale*100]" info:`
convert barn.jpg -virtual-pixel white -define distort:viewport=${ww}x${hh}+${xx}+${yy} -filter point -distort SRT "$rotate" +repage -resize $scale% test.jpg
```

[image]

Note that ImageMagick -distort SRT permits scaling, but the scale is done before the cropping from the viewport. So I had to use the viewport crop first and then add -resize in percent (as scale=2 --> scale=200%)

The reason I used -distort SRT with the viewport crop is that it would allow offset cropping when the xx and yy values are negative. You cannot do that with a simple -crop.

So for example:

```
ww=320
hh=180
xx=-40
yy=-60
rotate=0
scale=1
scale=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$scale*100]" info:`
convert barn.jpg -virtual-pixel white -define distort:viewport=${ww}x${hh}+${xx}+${yy} -filter point -distort SRT "$rotate" +repage -resize $scale% test2.jpg
```

[image]

If you download the image, you will see it is padded at the top and right with white, but still has a size of 320x180.

If you are cropping only within the bounds of the image, then you can use -crop and the Imagemagick command would be:

```
ww=320
hh=180
xx=40
yy=60
rotate=0
scale=2
scale=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$scale*100]" info:`
convert barn.jpg -crop ${ww}x${hh}+${xx}+${yy} +repage -resize $scale% test4.jpg
```

[image]

Which produces the same results as my original viewport crop.

Comment: any idea how to support rotate ? Is it possible without recalculation of new x-y after rotation (the image size will become bigger)

Comment: I do not understand the question. Please provide and example and/or more details about exactly what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

I've had success just using the data from `getData` without doing any math on the results.

```
var croppable = $('.croppable');
croppable.cropper({
  autoCrop: true, 
  viewMode: 0,
  background: false,
  modal: true,
  zoomable: true,
  responsive: false, 
  crop: function(e) {
    data = croppable.cropper('getData');
    $('#extract_image_crop_x').val(data.x);
    $('#extract_image_crop_y').val(data.y);
    $('#extract_image_crop_width').val(data.width);
    $('#extract_image_crop_height').val(data.height);
    $('#extract_image_crop_rotate').val(data.rotate);
  }
});
```